# Please help me to compile this C program? [Linux]

Tags: c, linux

I am using Linux now, and trying to compile this by gcc BUT.......

this is my truly simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("Hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

and this is so much weird output:

```
./try.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./try.c: line 3: `int main(){'
```

why is it?

I have tried the right way to compile it, such:

1. `gcc file_name.c -o file_name` and other types of way of compiling
2. `chmod +rwx file_name.c`
3. `./file_name.c`

but still I got that result, why?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute the *.c* file, remove the trailing *.c* from the name of the file you want to execute.

Like this:

1. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -o executable file_name.c`
2. You should not need to make it executable, it should already be executable since the compiler will do that.
3. `./executable`

As you see, I've passed some parameters to *gcc* to let it help in diagnosing problems, sometimes these problems are caused by your lack of knowledge and some other times because you write code quickly and miss some details. So using them is good (*although compilation is slower, but that doesn't matter if you have a good and fast machine, wehreas having issues in the code does matter*).

The meaning of these flags are as follows

1. `-Wall` Enable all warnings. *Really some are not enabled*, but most are.
2. `-Wextra` Enable extra warnings.
3. `-pedantic` make the compiler pedantic, i.e. stick strictly to the desired (*default for this version of gcc*) standard.
4. `-Werror` Consider that warnings are **errors**.

Also, you could have guessed this if you see what the error says

```
./try.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./try.c: line 3: `int main(){'
```

as you can see the shell is trying to execute the source code as if it was a shell script, so you can immediately notice that this is not the executable file generated by *gcc*, and then you would notice the *.c* in the file name.

Comment: @EdHeal You are right, I just copied it from the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile the code first.

Follow these steps.

```
gcc try.c -o try.out
```

to compile the code. The `-o` option is given to give a custom name to the executable that will be produced.

Then, you can run it by typing

```
./try.out
```

To run the executable.

---

Be informed though, that there are a number of command line options that you can use to get the information about your code and add more functionality. See [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html) page for more information.

Comment: This is simpler than what the OP has, the question suggests that the OP is very new to [tag:c]! I would (*and I did*) intentionally write `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic try.c` to make them use compilation warning and get used to that, IMHO that would help them learn the language and good practice.

Comment: @iharob, Yes, but then you should explain the meaning of each and every argument.

Comment: I think you should get them to crawl first - but point them to using the manual page

Comment: @EdHeal, I just did. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
gcc try.c
./a.out
```

Compiles the code and runs it. Please read the manual page for gcc and there are many delights to behold (extra checking etc)

Comment: So far this answer is answering the problem. But basicly when i code python program, i could just give it to executable permission and run it by $: ./try.c   , but here is not the case, can you explain the $: ./a.out ?

anyway thank you for answering this.

Comment: Please read the manual page for the gcc compiler. Python is a different beast.- it is interpreted.

Comment: @KalbyImanie Python is an interpreted programming language, when you do that you have to add `#!/usr/bin.python` as the first line in your file then the shell will do `/usr/bin/python my-python-script.py` on your script. The [tag:c] programming language is not interpreted, it's compiled. You create executable files with the compiler and you could delete the source if you want, the file should execute anyway. I think you should research the difference between Interpreted Programming Languages, Compiled Programming Languages and Java.